# duplicate symbol error C++

Tags: c++

I have added some const character in my file as under. The error i get  is duplicate symbol _xyz(say). What is the problem with it and how could i get out of this.

```
const char* xyz = "xyz";
class Abc
{
public:
    Abc()
    {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 73):

If this is in a header file, you're defining `xyz` every time you `#include` it.

You can change the declaration as @R Samuel Klatchko shows. The usual way (if the data isn't `const`) is like this:

In Abc.h:

```
extern char *xyz;
```

In Abc.cpp:

```
char *xyz = "xyz";
```

**Edited to add**

Note that header guards will **not** solve this problem:

```
#ifndef XYZ_H
#define XYZ_H
...
#endif
```

Header guards prevent "redefinition" errors, where the same symbol appears twice in the same compilation unit. That's a **compiler** error.

But even with header guards the definition of `xyz` will still appear in every source file that includes it, causing a "duplicate symbol" error, which is a **linker** error.

Comment: Declaring a variable multiple times is not an error (if it's not within the same translation unit). Defining it is.

Comment: Thanks for the header guard clarification. Here is a weird thing, though - I only get the linker error for duplicated symbols if I have a function defined in that header. In my current case I have a bunch of constants and a couple of functions defined in a namespace within a header - I only get linker error for the functions, const's are OK. Why is that?

Answer (score 13):

I also ran into this issue, but for me the solution was different. I had put overloaded operators (==, !=, <<) in my header file and implemented them. This was causing an issue in other files where I also used ==, !=, or <<. To solve this, I moved the implementation into the .cpp file and left the declaration in the header file.

**Edit**:

This can also be caused if:

- You are including `.cpp` files instead of `.h` files. You can fix this by switching the import to use `.h` instead of `.cpp`.
- You are implementing static functions inside a header file (outside of the class declaration). You can fix this by moving the implementations into a `.cpp` file (among other solutions).

Comment: Alternatively add the `static` keyword in front of the operators if you have a header only library.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is every source file that includes your header file gets it's own copy of `xyz` with external linkage.

The easiest way to fix that is to give `xyz` internal linkage.  You can do that by making the pointer itself const in addition to having the underlying char's const:

```
const char* const xyz = "xyz";
```

Comment: const is definitely good, but this just hides the problem that there is an instance of the same data from every file now.

Answer (score 0):

My use-case:

- I had multiple header files `a.hpp`, `b.hpp`, and, `c.hpp` which contained some utility methods.
- I had a file `util.hpp` which acted as an aggregator for the above files.

In my case, the `extern` did not work but `static` worked.

I had to use:

- `header guards` to avoid errors in Visual Studio code.
- `static` with functions to avoid compile-time errors.

Check out this [article](https://chunminchang.github.io/blog/post/how-to-avoid-duplicate-symbols-when-compiling) too.