# Multiple declarations and definitions

Tags: c

Content of `X.c`:

```
int i;
main ()
{
fun ();
}
```

Content of `Y.c`:

```
int i;
fun ()
{
}
```

Why does these two files compile with no error ? (using GCC)

But if i use `int i = 10;` it prints a multiple definition error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c & c++ default global variable linkage, multiple declaration & definition problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371048/c-c-default-global-variable-linkage-multiple-declaration-definition-probl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be interested in this question and the answers. Keywords: "tentative definition".

[Tentative definitions in C99 and linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490693/tentative-definitions-in-c99-and-linking)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really want an **independent** variable called i in each of these two files, you need to prefix them with `static` in order to give them [internal linkage.](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter4/linkage.html)

```
static int i = 10;
```

If you want i to be the same variable in both files, so changes in one affect the other, use the answers you were [given 3 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910660/how-do-i-avoid-this-linking-error) when you asked a variant of the question. If it is to be shared, you need to define the variable in one place.

As to why it didn't cause an error without the init, I think that's because you weren't using the variable until it needed initializing and so the compiler ignored it.

Answer (score -1):

Because there is a difference between a declaration and a definition. `int i;` does nothing more than introducing a name. `int i = 10;` on the other hand defines `i`, hence, a place in the memory must be reserved to store the value it corresponds to. But it is impossible for the compiler to know which value corresponds to `i` as you want to associate two memory locations with the name `i`.

This is under the assumption that you link these files against eachother, which is not entirely clear from your explanation.

Comment: No, `int i;` is also a definition.

Comment: Indeed, I misinterpreted his example, I'm sorry.

Comment: i'm confused, is it definition ?