# C++ Header File and Linker Errors

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

I'm getting stranger error when I compile my code. I guess the header files aren't being properly linked because every single one of those variables that are erroring have been specified in 'variables.h' which I properly #include. Strangely enough, if I comment ou the areas in which the variables are used in main.cpp, a whole other slew of errors pop up of the same variables in another file readfile.cpp. Below is the error output, as well as my code for main.cpp and variables.h. Any ideas?

```
g++ -c main.cpp 
g++ -c readfile.cpp 
g++ -c Objects.cpp 
g++ -o raytracer main.o readfile.o Objects.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_depth", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
      readFile(char const*)in readfile.o
  "_diffuse", referenced from:
      readFile(char const*)in readfile.o
  "_emission", referenced from:
      readFile(char const*)in readfile.o
  "_filename", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
  "_fov", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
      initCamera(float*)in readfile.o
  "_height", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
      readFile(char const*)in readfile.o
  "_lookatx", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
      initCamera(float*)in readfile.o
  "_lookaty", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
      initCamera(float*)in readfile.o
  "_lookatz", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
      initCamera(float*)in readfile.o
  "_lookfromx", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
      initCamera(float*)in readfile.o
  "_lookfromy", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
      initCamera(float*)in readfile.o
  "_lookfromz", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
      initCamera(float*)in readfile.o
  "_maxvertnorms", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
      readFile(char const*)in readfile.o
  "_maxverts", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
      readFile(char const*)in readfile.o
  "_shininess", referenced from:
      readFile(char const*)in readfile.o
  "_specular", referenced from:
      readFile(char const*)in readfile.o
  "_spherecount", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
  "_spheres", referenced from:
      readFile(char const*)in readfile.o
  "_triangles", referenced from:
      readFile(char const*)in readfile.o
  "_tricount", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
  "_trinormals", referenced from:
      readFile(char const*)in readfile.o
  "_trinormcount", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
  "_upx", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
      initCamera(float*)in readfile.o
  "_upy", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
      initCamera(float*)in readfile.o
  "_upz", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
      initCamera(float*)in readfile.o
  "_vertexcount", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
  "_vertexnormcount", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
  "_vertices", referenced from:
      readFile(char const*)in readfile.o
  "_vertnormals", referenced from:
      readFile(char const*)in readfile.o
  "_width", referenced from:
      init()    in main.o
      readFile(char const*)in readfile.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Below is variables.h..

```
#include "vertexnormal.h"
#include "sphere.h"
#include "tri.h"
#include "trinormal.h"
#include "vec.h"

#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// width and height specify image size
extern float width;
extern float height;

// maximum depth for a ray (level of recursion)
extern int depth;

// the output file to which the image should be written
extern string filename;

// camera specifiations (should i put in a struct?)
extern float lookfromx;
extern float lookfromy;
extern float lookfromz;
extern float lookatx;
extern float lookaty;
extern float lookatz;
extern float upx;
extern float upy;
extern float upz;
extern float fov;

//***************************//
//  Geometry Specifications  //
//***************************//

// specifies the number of vertrices for tri specifications
extern int maxverts;

// specifies the number of vertices with normals for tri specifications
extern int maxvertnorms;

// pile of inputted vertices
// might need to #include glm file                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
extern vector<vec> vertices;

// pile of inputted vertices with specified normals
extern vector<vertexNormal> vertnormals;

// pile of inputted spheres
extern vector<sphere> spheres;

// pile of inputted triangles
extern vector<tri> triangles;

// pile of inputted triangles using vertices with specified normals 
extern vector<triNormal> trinormals;

extern int vertexcount;
extern int vertexnormcount;
extern int spherecount;
extern int tricount;
extern int trinormcount;

//**************************//
//  Materials Specifiations //
//**************************//

extern float diffuse[3];
extern float specular[3];
extern float shininess;
extern float emission[3];
```

And here is my main.cpp,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

#include "Objects.h"

using namespace std;

#include "readfile.h"
#include "variables.h"


void init() {
    cout << "Reading in scene file... \n";
    cout << "Image size has been set to a " << width << " x " << height << " output. /n";
    cout << "The maximum recursion depth has been set to " << depth << ". \n";
    cout << "The image will be output to " << filename << ".png. \n";

    cout << "The camera has been instantiated with the following properties: \n";
    cout << "\t POSITION: (" << lookfromx << ", " << lookfromy << ", " << lookfromz << ") \n";
    cout << "\t DIRECTION: (" << lookatx << ", " << lookaty << ", " << lookatz << ") \n";
    cout << "\t UP: (" << upx << ", " << upy << ", " << upz << ") \n";
    cout << "\t FIELD OF VIEW: " << fov << " \n";

    cout << "An amount of " << vertexcount << " vertices has been specified with a maximum of " << maxverts << " allowed. \n";
    cout << "An amount of " << vertexnormcount << " vertices with normals has been specified with a maximum of " << maxvertnorms << " allowed. \n"; 

    cout << "An amount of " << spherecount << " spheres have been specified. \n";
    cout << "An amount of " << tricount << " triangles have been specified. \n";
    cout << "An amount of " << trinormcount << " triangles with calculated vertex normals have been specified. \n";
}


int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    readFile(argv[1]);
    init();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you please reduce the code to a smaller example that exhibits the same behaviour? Far over 90% of your question is irrelevant to the actual problem. By eliminating code, you might even be able to find the problem yourself.

Comment: That is a truly spectacular number of global variables. After you've figured out how to use global variables correctly, **the very next thing** you should learn is how to structure your code so you don't need to use them. You really aren't going to get very far with this style of coding. Perhaps read up on *object orientation*, it's what the C++ language was invented for. Or even just read about *function parameters* and *return values*.

Comment: @john  Yeah, I understand it's quite a bit of global vars, but a lot of graphics applications run as a state machine so there's a tendency to have an inflated number of variables to keep track of. About a fourth of the variables up there are for debugging purposes and the only variables that I can agree may be implemented better are the camera specification parameters. I did it this way because I'm just trying to get a text parser up and running as quickly as possible. Regardless, thanks again for all the help and advice. It works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

1. Open up your variables.h header file.
2. Copy ALL of the `extern` variable declarations.
3. Open up your main.cpp file.
4. Paste all your declarations copied from (2).
5. In the same main.cpp **remove** the keyword `extern` from each declaration.
6. Save all your files.
7. Lookup how `extern` works. Something tells me you missed that in your studies.

Ok, this has been covered in SO what, a few thousand times, but for the OP:

**Declaring the Existence of a Variable**

```
// DECLARE myvar, an int variable. no storage has been set aside
//  this is simply telling the compiler this thing exists.. somewhere.
extern int myvar;
```

**Defining The Existence of a Variable**

```
// DEFINE myvar, an int variable. storage *is* set aside here.
//  only ONE of these, by this name, can be in your global 
//  namespace in your program.
int myvar = 0;
```

Traditionally, `extern` declarations are in headers, but definitions are **always** in c/cpp files. There **must** be a matching definition for any `extern`-declared variable that is used in your program.

**How this fits with your situation**
All of your variables were *declared* in `variables.h`, but the were never *defined* anyway. By telling you to copy/paste all those declarations into a source file (any will do; I chose main.cpp because it was already in your project), and then *removing* the `extern` keyword *in that source file (not the header)*, you were essentially **defining** where they all officially existed. Now all those references to `extern`'ed variables in your other source files finally have something to hook up to at link time.

**Sidebar**
In the c/cpp file where your variables are being **defined**, make sure you initialize them to proper values. This is the one and only place you can do it. you can NOT do it on any `extern` declaration. It can only be done on a **definition**.

Header File

```
extern int myvar; // note: no initial value.
```

Source File

```
int myvar = 0; // note: initialized to zero (0)
```

I *hope* that made at least a little sense.

Comment: Thanks WhozCraig for the response. I'd like to keep them out of my main.cpp, if possible. Would there be a way around it if I removed the extern keyword from 'variables.h'?

Comment: 'I'd like to keep them out of main.cpp if possible'. They have to go somewhere, if not main.cpp then another .cpp file. Maybe even create a .cpp file called globals.cpp. And no just removing extern will not work. But of course the real answer is don't use global variables at all. Maybe you can use this as a learning experience, try to rewrite your code so you don't need globals. As your comment says putting them in a struct would be a start. Then all you need to learn is how to pass variables from one function to another.

Comment: @KevinPamplona: No, that leads to multiple definitions. Keep in mind that `#include` *literally* just includes the contents of a file - each time you `#include` a definition you get a new one. Keep `extern` in the header, then add the definitions (without `extern`) in a relevant `.cpp` file. Or better yet: don't use global variables at all.

Comment: Yeah, what John said. if nothing else create a variables.cpp file and throw them all in there, but **keep the extern qualifier in front of all the ones in variables.h** And during your swearing while having to put all those `extern` decls back in variables.h, think of it as motivation to *not have so many global vars* =)

Answer (score 0):

```
extern float lookfromx;
extern float lookfromy;
extern float lookfromz;
extern float lookatx;
extern float lookaty;
extern float lookatz;
```

These are simply declarations. You need to define these variables somewhere in the program (in variables.cpp, for example). To make these definitions you can either

- remove the extern keyword
- add an initialiizer ( = value; )

Comment: Thanks Armen. It worked, sorta. Now I'm getting duplicate errors such as 'duplicate symbol _lookfromx in:
    main.o
    readfile.o
duplicate symbol _lookfromy in:
    main.o
    readfile.o' --- To remedy this, I tried removing #include "variables.h" from readfile.cpp, but then I get "not declared" errors. How can I remedy the duplicate problem?

Comment: @KevinPamplona: You have to leave the declarations in the .h file and have the definitions in the .cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable.h file simply makes your variables portable across other files in the global scope, but they still need to be declared. Make sure to declare the actual variables in your main file(normal method of initialization).

> The extern keyword declares a variable or function and specifies that it has external linkage (its name is visible from files other than the one in which it's defined). When modifying a variable, extern specifies that the variable has static duration (it is allocated when the program begins and deallocated when the program ends). The variable or function may be defined in another source file, or later in the same file. Declarations of variables and functions at file scope are external by default.

[Read more on the extern keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0603949d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Need4Sleep. I removed the extern keyword as Armen below suggested, but now I'm getting duplicate symbol errors. Removing #include "variables.h" in readfile.cpp didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: make sure your variables.h file is not included multiple times, this could be the problem for your duplicate. Add header guards that you would usually see in a class header file

Comment: 'variables.h' is only declared once in readfile and main, but i don't have any header guards--could that be the problem?

Comment: Doesnt hurt to add them, give it a try. Shouldnt take more than a minute

Comment: Hm, I encased variables.h in a header guard, but the duplicate error still sticks around.

Comment: all of the vars you declared in another file have an initial value right? if anything assign zero to them. Take a look at this guys problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894957/duplicate-symbol-error-c

Comment: @KevinPamplona That's because you misunderstand what include guards do. You seem to be resisting the correct solution which all three answers have already told you (some answers are perhaps clearer than others).